# how do I check in android studio which file in my app is consuming too much memory (Flutter, Android Studio)

Tags: flutter

I have noticed that some pages in my apps, seem to be consuming more memory as my laptop's fanspeed increases when i land on those pages. I am using Android studio to build my app. Is there a way to check which pages are consuming more memory or making the fanspeed increase??
Thank you for all your help.

Comment: checkout here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/memory